# MapBox incorrect driving time estimate

Tags: mapbox

Using MapBox's driving API, these 2 coordinates show an estimate of **13h**+.
`103.7438696,1.495984; 103.6637688,1.5001924`

13 hours for Traffic, Driving and Walking. But **1h 20m** for Cycling.

Does anyone know what contributes to the excessive estimate? Google shows **20mins** and it's just about right.

---

**Update 16:49 GMT+8**
Seems to be a system-wide issue. Affects our locations in MY, NZ, AU, PH, SG. All our delivery systems are misestimating delivery times and making customers really angry and reluctant to place orders.

Both happens using their library and their PlayGround.

Comment: Same here. Een technical support request can be made here: https://support.mapbox.com/hc/en-us/

Comment: Problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, we did file tickets (turnaround time is 3 days lol). Confirmed resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue within the MapBox platform and has been resolved. Quoting their status update here.

**Directions/Map Matching APIs ETA Accuracy**

- **May 10, 12:31 UTC - Resolved** - This incident has been resolved.
- **May 10, 11:16 UTC - Monitoring** - A fix has been implemented and we are monitoring the results.
- **May 10, 10:23 UTC - Identified** - We are currently experiencing an issue with our Directions and Map Matching APIs where our ETAs are inaccurate. We have identified the issue and are working on a fix.

Ref: [MapBox Status](https://status.mapbox.com/)